# Are the orders of a $p$-adic field complete rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a $p$-adic field and let $\mathcal O_K$ be its ring of integers.
Consider a monic polynomial $f\in \mathcal{O}_K[x]$ and assume that it is irreducible.

Is the ring $\mathcal {O}_K[x]/(f)$ a complete ring?

Comment: I'll assume by 'complete' you mean a complete local ring. The answer then is yes. Here's a quick reason to see why, and, if you're not happy, I could perhaps give another attempt at an answer. Namely, choose a root $\alpha$ of $f$ in $\overline{K}$ (where I've fixed some algebraic closure of $K$) and consider $L=K(\alpha)$. Then, I assume you're happy with the well-known fact that $\mathcal{O}_L$ is complete. Thus, it suffices to note that $\mathcal{O}_K[x]/(f)=\mathcal{O}_K[\alpha]$ is a closed subset of $\mathcal{O}_L$ and thus also complete when given the subspace topology.

Comment: I leave it to you to verify that this topology agrees with the $\mathfrak{m}$-adic topology on $\mathcal{O}_K[x]/(f)$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Remember that the projections are continuous, open maps, and since the top ring is locally compact, the image of a compact (resp. open) set is compact (resp. open). But then the image is locally compact, which implies complete. The usual lattice isomorphism theorem --sometimes called the fourth isomorphism theorem)--implies the locality.